# Counting number of faces in Real time in python video

Tags: python, windows, opencv, real-time

I am trying to create a face detection system in python using openCV that counts the total number of faces.(also it is detecting the eyes of the person).
But i want it to give the exact number of faces it detected say, by the end of day in real time.
following is the code.. any suggestions please:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Python27\Scripts\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Python27\Scripts\haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f=img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    print(len(faces))
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(f,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = f[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',f)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img.release()
```

Comment: What  is the question ?

Comment: The question is to track number of people in real time...any suggestions please

Comment: Where are you exactly facing the issues ?

Comment: how do i calculate number of images for start time and end time here.. this code is giving me no of faces for every second till the webcam is turned on

Comment: and also how do i achieve accuracy in this... as if half of my face is visible in the webcam... then it does not detect it.. i am confused..

Comment: @Radhika , did you find any solution to this? I am also facing similar issues.